# "self" in normal method vs. "self" in singleton method?

Tags: ruby, singleton, self

Is self the same in both of these cases?

```
class Person
   def who_am_i?
     puts self       # self?
   end
end

ted = Person.new
def ted.singleton_who_am_i?
   puts self         # self?
end

ted.who_am_i?
ted.singleton_who_am_i?
```

Comment: Well, you tried it, and what did you get? -1 because it's one copy'n'paste away and *could* easily have been a useful question. What does `self` *mean* when the *method is invoked*? (`self` is a keyword and *not* a bound variable.)

Comment: Just trying to understand better the scope / environment during each execution. I know it is a bit different in each. Don't get upset :)

Comment: So ... run it. What happens? Was it expected? If not, why not? Then formulate *that* into a question. You may be interested in just returning `self` (e.g. no "puts") because then you could also do `ted.who_am_i? == test.singleton_who_am_i?`, for instance.

Comment: Also, if you run the expressions on the REPL (and let the REPL print the results instead of using "puts") it will use `inspect` by default (and not `to_s`) which is often handier in playing around.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it appears so:

```
class Person
  def who_am_i?
    puts self.to_yaml
  end
end

ted = Person.new
def ted.singleton_who_am_i?
  puts self.to_yaml
end

ted.who_am_i?
--- !ruby/object:Person {}

ted.singleton_who_am_i?
--- !ruby/object:Person {}
```

Comment: That is correct. Can you expand on the behavior of `self` and *what it means* (esp. in context of *inside a method*) though?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
  def bar
    p self
  end
end

class << Foo
  def bar
    p self
  end
end

Foo.bar              #Foo (the class itself)
Foo.new.bar          #<Foo:0x10acc70> (a Foo class object)
```

When the context is in a object, self is the object.

When the context is in the class, self is the class.

Also I do know if "singleton" is a good word for Ruby because in Ruby, even a class is an object, and "singleton" simply adds method to an existing object.

Comment: This is true, but subtly different than the original question. And "singleton" is an *awful* term because it is so overloaded ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Singleton methods are instance methods only a certain object responds to. Here's how this is implemented:

1. The object's *singleton class* is opened;
2. Ruby defines your singleton method as an *instance method* of the singleton class.

What is not apparent here is the actual relationship between the actual class and singleton class. One could say it sits *between* the class and the object.

More precisely, the singleton class *inherits* from the actual class, and actually *is* the object's class.

Why doesn't [`Object#class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-class) return the singleton class, you ask? Well, it simply skips over it. [Yeah](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L158).

Here's an example. Given the following class:

```
class Person
  def instance; self end  # self is the Person instance here
end

person = Person.new
```

If we wanted to define a singleton method for `person`, we could write this:

```
class << person
  def singleton; self end  # What is self in this context?
end
```

This is roughly equivalent to this:

```
class SingletonPerson < Person
  def singleton; self end  # self is the Person instance here too!
end

person = SingletonPerson.new
```

The main difference is that Ruby knows that `SingletonPerson` is a singleton class, so when you call `person.class` you actually get `Person` and not `SingletonPerson`.

This effectively hides all this complexity from you, which is a great thing. However, it is also great to understand how things work under the hood. The same logic here applies to class methods, which are really just singleton methods of a `Class` or `Module` instance.

Comment: Yes, but `self` inside a class (or class singleton) is not the same as the `self` inside a method. Inside a method `self` *always* evaluates to the receiver (the object the message was sent to). (This is *the* object that the message was sent to, independent of how many parent classes or singletons there are in the MRO.)